# Winmerge - how do I exclude a -specific- file (Thumbs.db) from folder comparison?

Tags: database, file, filter, winmerge

I am comparing two folders in Winmerge.
I have already created a filter that excludes all .ini files from the comparison process.
Here's how I'm doing that:

myfilt.flt

```
name: exclinis
desc: exclude all ini files from comparison

def: include

f: \.ini$ ##file filt to exclude all .ini files
d: \\subdir$ ##filt for dir
```

How do I exclude a **specific** file, i.e.  Thumbs.db  ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `e: Thumbs\.db$` ? These filters seem to be a simple list of regexps?

Comment: Aha - that did it, well actually I tried the ```e:``` but it didn't work, but the ```f: Thumbs\.db$``` did !  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:
`f: \Thumbs.db`